# Unicorn does not always install media items correctly

Tags: media-library, unicorn

On occasions, Unicorn does not pick up changes to media items in Sitecore correctly. e.g. after installing a package of UAT content into my local environment the other day, I noticed that some of the serialized media items had been created on disk but with the blob field left empty. Using **Developer > Serialize tree** seemed to trigger the blob data to be saved to the items correctly. However, I am finding that during deployment (synchronization), the media blobs are often missed so we have media items which are "empty" (with no attachment).

*I'm aware that this question might be a bit vague and some details might be dependent on our particular CI/deployment setup, but hoping someone has experienced a similar issue before and has an idea of the solution.*

Comment: Are they big sized images? Do you have anything related to this in log files?

Comment: Check the yml files on the deployed server to see if they look correct on disk. If so, in the developer tab, hit Revert Item on the media item. What I'm trying to determine is whether or not it's getting deployed to the server, but not correctly sync'd

Comment: Versioned or Unversioned media?

Comment: @MarkCassidy It seems that the images under /sitecore/content/.../Sitename/Media are Versioned, whereas the ones under /sitecore/media library are Unversioned.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this symptom before, and eventually found out that it was due to the media items not existing in the language of the site (but since the blob field is Shared, the content editor would recognize it). This combined with a deployment/publish step that only handled items in explicitly defined languages.

Also, don't be fooled by a well-rendered thumbnail, sometimes the thumbnail works, but the original item has become corrupted.

*I hope this helps someone, considering this question is already 6 months old.*